# Force BottomSheet to hide when user is dragging

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am trying to force my `BottomSheet` to hide even when user is dragging.

For the discussion let's say that my app only contains two views :
- `Button`
- `BottomSheet`

At the beginning the `BottomSheet` is expanded. When I click the button I want the `BottomSheet` to completely hide, no matter if the user is dragging. I thought I would just have to set the `BottomSheet`'s state to collapsed or hidden, but this only works if the user is not dragging the `BottomSheet`. If he's dragging, then nothing happens and the `BottomSheet` remains visible.

Here is what I've tried :
- set `peekHeight` to 0
- set state to `hidden`
- set state to `collapsed`

But none of this worked.

Any idea ?

Comment: How the user is able to click button if he is dragging the view.?

Comment: The button is not inside the bottomSheet so it is clickable

Comment: Actually your question just made me think of disabling the button when the bottomSheet is dragged

Comment: Don't try to change the state of BottomSheetBehavior when it is dragging. Change your logic according to the situation.

Comment: @LvN In the Google Maps app when the user draggs the bottomSheet and clicks the back button at the same time, the bottomSheet collapses, so there has to be way

Comment: If you want to collapse the bottom sheet on button click, there are ways like,
if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING ||
                mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED 
                ) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work

Comment: @LvN The state changes, but the the bottomSheet does not collapse

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mBottomSheetBehavior.isHideable()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else {
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
    }
}
```